# How can i update multiple databases at the same time in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have 7 databases. Databases have same tables. I want to update all of them at the same time when i edit row or add new row. If one of transactions doesn't work , It will not be updated.

How can i update?

Comment: why do you have duplicate tables in a server?

Comment: Those are actually different tables which happen to hold the same data. Right?

Comment: DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION  ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-distributed-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Try using USE database_name; write your UPDATE statements then GO

Comment: cross-database transactions don't use distributed transactions
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/understanding-cross-database-transactions-in-sql-server/

Comment: @rsjaffe i have one database for each country for example: for TURKEY -> TurkeyDB
for USA -> UsaDB

Comment: To my knowledge, the architecture is weird... To repeat 7 times everything you do in 7 databases... mmm, sounds strange.

Comment: I'd support AsRa's answer on this--databases can use tables stored in another database. I'm not aware of any drawbacks to accessing a table from another database. Does anybody have a good use case for duplicating tables in different databases?

Comment: @EmreD.--I feel your pain. But is there a way to fix the architecture now?

Comment: @EmreD., whilst you think about changing that architecture, you can try with the trigger proposed in one of the answer, but you should replicate it in each database/table in which you have to replicate the data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why you need the same tables with the same data in different databases. IMHO you need redesign your application and database. 
Possible solutions:

1. Common schema and data move to single database
2. If you nevertheless need data duplication you can change data in single database, and use transactional replication for data delivery to other databases.
3. You need use cross-database transactions

-

```
 begin try
    begin transaction;
    update db1..table1 set field1 = value1, field2 = value2 where key = @key;
    update db2..table1 set field1 = value1, field2 = value2 where key = @key;
    ...
    update dbN..table1 set field1 = value1, field2 = value2 where key = @key;
    commit transaction;
end try
begin catch
    SELECT   
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber, ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity, 
        ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState, ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
        ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine, ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  
    if @@trancount > 0  
        rollback transaction;  
end catch
```

Comment: not same data, databases have different data for each country

Comment: you can still use cross-database transactions. use multipart objects identifiers to access objects in different databases
[database_name].[schema_name].[objects_name].

Answer (score 2):

You can add all your servers/databases to one group in ***Registered servers*** pane (SQL Management Studio(2016): Ctrl + Alt + G to show it). Under local serves Groups.

Then press right button on a new group and select "New Query".

When you execute query it will run on all servers in selected group.

Comment: This is the only answer provided that is worth anything. There are definitely valid reasons to have data separated into multiple databases with similar/identical schemas.

Answer (score 0):

Update or Modify a single table and use the same table across different databases. That is better than trying to maintain data consistency across 7 tables in 7 databases!

Answer (score 0):

I think trigger can help you below is sudo code and use roll back transaction if fails

```
USE Test;--Test is one db
    GO
    CREATE TRIGGER afterInsert ON table AFTER INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN 
      IF @@rowcount = 0 RETURN;

      UPDATE Test2.[schema_name(default schema is dbo)].Clients --here test2 is another db
      SET col = col +1 -- or whatever it should be
      FROM Test2.[schema_name(default schema is dbo)].Clients c
      INNER JOIN inserted i ON ([your join condition])
    END;  
    GO
```